# Add button to table row td when fetching data ajax java

Tags: javascript, java, html, ajax

For my course purpose I want to create a dynamic data table using ajax. Here's my Javascript code:

```
$("#submitcateg").click(function(){
   var categ = $("#addcategname").val();
   $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "ProcatServlet",
       data: {"categ":categ, "id":"addcateg"},
       success: function(data){
           if(data=="true"){
               $("#addcategname").hide();
               $("#submitcateg").hide();
               $("#categtable").show(function(){
       $.ajax({
           type: "GET",
           url: "ProcatServlet",
           data: {"id":"getcateg"},
           success: function(responseJson) {
               if(responseJson!=null) {
                   $("#categtable").find("tr:gt(0)").remove();
                   var tablebody = document.getElementById("categtable").getElementsByTagName("tbody");
                   $.each(responseJson, function(key, value){
                      var button = document.createElement("input");
                      button.type="button";
                      button.id="edit";
                      button.value="edit";
                      var rowNew =  $("<tr><td></td><td></td></tr>");
                      rowNew.children().eq(0).text(value);
                      rowNew.children().eq(1).append(button);
                      rowNew.appendTo(tablebody);
                   });
               }
           }
       });
   });
               $("#addcategtrigger").show();
           } else {
               alert("failed");
           }
       }
   });
 });
```

Using this code, I can show the data and assigned it to the table perfectly, but when I'm trying to add a button to the next column on the row, the button didn't appear. Please help me where I'm doing it wrong.